Intl.DateTimeFormat error only on Node.js - bug?
The documentation for Intl.DateTimeFormat() states that you can pass UTC offsets as a value for the timeZone option:

Additionally, time zones can be given as UTC offsets in the format
"±hh:mm", "±hhmm", or "±hh", for example as "+01:00", "-2359", or
"+23".

However the following code fails on Node.js:
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
                    day: "2-digit",
                    month: "long",
                    year: "numeric",
                    hour: "numeric",
                    minute: "2-digit",
                    hour12: true,
                    timeZone: "+04:30", // throws error
                  }).format(new Date())

It throws an error saying:

"RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: +04:30"

How can it be an error when offset values are allowed? I cannot give a Timezone name like "GMT" because some offsets have no name.
The same code runs fine on the front-end:


console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
                    day: "2-digit",
                    month: "long",
                    year: "numeric",
                    hour: "numeric",
                    minute: "2-digit",
                    hour12: true,
                    timeZone: "+04:30",
                  }).format(new Date()))



It works perfectly. But if I run it on Node.js it fails. Does Node have a different implementation of Intl.DateTimeFormat?

As of v22 Node.js now supports UTC offset as a timeZone.
